# Default SSH passphrase as generated by openssl req

Tags: azure, ssh, openssl

I'm using a script that generates a private/public key pair using the `openssl` command. It uses the following line :

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 \
          -subj '/O=Weaveworks, Inc./L=London/C=GB/CN=weave.works' \
          -keyout ./ssh.key -out ./ssh.pem
```

([ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/README.md))

The issue is, when I try to use the generated key, it's asking me for a passphrase. My understanding is that if I don't specify a passphrase, none will be set. But when I try to add it, I get asked for one:

```
$ ssh-add ssh.key
```

Is there a default passphrase that's set up when `openssl` is used?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` as expected? The thing you are doing using `openssl` is not a keypair usable by `openssh`. If openssh is unable to decode the key without passphrase, it asks for one, but it can also mean that the format is wrong.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for the reply. I also use `ssh-keygen` to generate keys, but this is used by Kubernetes: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/lib/azure_wrapper.js#L99 I'm not sure why they use this, but then they say one should `ssh` to the server using this key.

Comment: I just tried it once again and your exact use case works for me without any problems on both Fedora and RHEL. What distro and openssh/openssl version are you using?

Comment: I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1k (8 Jan 2015) from Mac OS X. You also tried to launch a Kubernetes cluster on Azure with the same script, and it worked well? You were not prompted for a passphrase while trying to SSH?

Comment: Or did you try doing an `ssh-add`, and you were not prompted by a passphrase? Thanks!

Comment: I tried just `ssh-add` and I was not prompted for a password. To set it up with Azure you will need more missing pieces.